# How to configure Azure secure Kubernetes service (HTTPS) from visual interface?

Tags: azure, security, ssl, https, kubernetes

I am exercising the Azure machine learning samples and try to consume the trained model by deploying it as a webservice.

But find no MSDN material for creating this as a secure Kubernetes service (HTTPS):
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/how-to-secure-web-service

The above link is not helpful in instructing how to configure a AKS as a secure service while creating.
Can I not just do it from Visual interface, as the above seems to have instructions only through the python SDK?

Comment: yes you obviously can.

Comment: Can you lead me to how this can done from the Azure visual interface?

Comment: you cant from Azure portal, because this happens on Kubernetes, not on Azure

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you point me to how this can be done for the Kubernetes service (AKS) created in Azure portal?

Comment: no, i have no idea what that python code does

Comment: I don't think you can enable the SSL when creating AKS. The document just shows that enable the SSL when attaching AKS to the ML, it's just for the communication, not for AKS.